# Change an Excel with Multiple columns and rows to QR code

Tags: python, qr-code

According to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIW3C.png), I have a database that contains 8 columns and also 27 rows. I wrote a code that I want this database to be converted to QR code. Do I have a problem?

My code is written for only one column ('Poro') and I want the values of 8 columns in each row to be converted into a `QR code`. How can I change the code?
OR , Another way is to put the converted QR codes of 8 columns in each row together in a picture or image.

```
for i, r in df.iterrows():
   value = r['Poro']
   filename = f'qr_{i:02d}.png'
   qr = qrcode.make(value)
   qr.save(filename)
   display(qr)
```

Comment: Your code only generates a value for `r['Poro']` - what have you tried to loop over the other columns? Your code generates a name based on the row number only `f'qr_{i:02d}.png'` - what have you tried to add a column number? How do you expect these duplicates to be named exactly, if you propose a naming scheme that's based on row and columns number?

Comment: Please include your attempts and explain what specific problems you run into - SO is here to help fix your solution, not to write it for you.

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to paste the QR code from the values of 8 columns in each row into a single image.

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to paste the qr code generated from values of up to 8 columns in each row ,So that 8 qr codes become an image, which is the result of putting these 8 QR codes together.

Comment: The G-code tag is for CNC and 3D printers.  I think there is a bar code named 'G-code', but that tag is not a good fit, it is for something else.